# Force response()->download() return HTTPS url

Tags: laravel, ssl, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, response

I have switched my Laravel 5.1 to HTTPS and everything seems fine, except the file download part.

The problem is response()->download() returns a HTTP link instead of HTTPS and I get a mixed content in Chrome, so the link is blocked.

And some code:

```
$headers = array
            (
                'Content-Type' => 'application/vnd.android.package-archive'
            );
return response()->download(config('custom.storage') . $apk->generated_filename, $apk->filename, $headers);
```

Comment: How bout a little bit of code :)

Comment: Did you update APP_URL in your .env?

Comment: I just tried updating APP_URL and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @ChinLeung I have updated the post with the affected code.

Comment: What is the value of your  `config('custom.storage')`?